# Flume interceptor to ignore input CSV file header while reading

Tags: java, flume

My input file reads:

```
Name,Age,Date
abc,26,2016-12-16 00:00:01
pqr,25,2016-12-17 12:00:00
```

My output file has to be :

```
Name,Age,Date
ABC,26,2016-12-16 05:30:01
PQR,25,2016-12-17 17:30:00
```

I am doing this file conversion and output file movement using FLUME-INTERCEPTOR.

I have written below logic. But there is an obvious exception `"Cannot parse Date".` Basically, I have to ignore the input file header i.e `Name,Age,Date`. How to achieve this with my below code

```
        SimpleDateFormat a = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date =new Date();

        String line = new String(startEventBody);


        String[] token = line.split(",");
        date=a.parse(token[2]);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);


        String b = a.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

        token[0] = token[0].toUpperCase();
        token[2]=token[2].replace(token[2], b);

        String newLine = "";
        for (String s : token) {
            newLine += s + ",";
        }

        newLine = newLine.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "");

        this.outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(newLine.getBytes().length);

        this.outputStream.write(newLine.getBytes());


        return this.outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.setLenient` of [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))

Without leaving first line of headings you can check sanity of date format as following

```
...

SimpleDateFormat a = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
a.setLenient(false);
Date date =new Date();
String line = new String(startEventBody);
String[] token = line.split(",");
if(a.parse(token[2], new ParsePosition(0)) != null){
  date = a.parse(token[2]);
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
  cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
  token[2] = a.format(cal.getTime()).toString(); //rewrites new date string to token[2] 
}

token[0] = token[0].toUpperCase();

...
```

**Note:** Of course you can also check for `String` `Date` instead of `DateFormat`.